# Spring-integration: Put message into JMS queue only if e-mails has been sent

Tags: email, spring-integration

I want to send a mail and only if this works put a message into a JMS queue.
How can I do it? I couldn't find any mail:outbound-gateway.

OBS: By now a am using publish-subscribe-channel, but this is not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> OBS: By now a am using publish-subscribe-channel, but this is not exactly what i need.

Why not?

There are several techniques to do this:

1. Publish subscribe channel with the JMS endpoint the second subscriber (mail `order="1"`, jms `order="2"`) (with `ignore-failures="false"` - the default).
2. Recipient List Router
3. [Expression Evaluating Request Handler Advice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain)